# How to force screen on at all activities?

Tags: android, android-screen

Is there a way to force screen on at all activities of app. I don't wanna in just one activity, as in case of `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`, but one command to all activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `abstract class BaseActivity`
that calls in `start()`

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

then make all the activities in your app extend the `BaseActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:keepScreenOn` attribute in `Views`. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:keepScreenOn

Comment: But it's equal to put the `getWindow()...` in each activity, it's not?

Comment: Yes it is equivalent to setting it on the window, see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#keepScreenOn The only catch is you will have to add it to some view in every activity